# URLSession: how to check what cookies were sent with the request?

Tags: swift, cookies, urlsession

There is no doubt that the `HTTPCookie` is indeed inside the `HTTPCookieStorage`, but I wonder if there is any way to confirm that it's being sent from programmatic standpoint?

Of course intercepting HTTP traffic via sniffers doesn't count.

Comment: What's your use case here, why doo you need this? Are there parts of your code you suspect are not sending the proper cookies? If yes, can you add more details about those?

Comment: @Cristik None, there is no case - it's just a random shower thought. Like, anyone can intercept an HTTP request, but how would one surpass the magic behind HTTPCookieStorage being used in URLSession and actually confirm if it sends what you think it should send programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check that programmatically - the notion of `HTTPCookieStorage` being configured on the `URLSessionConfiguration` leads to it completely obscuring the Cookie-related details from the programmer. It operates like magic way out of scope of your vision.

To be honest, I couldn't even tell you that happens if you set Cookie header manually via `allHTTPHeaderFields` but if there were already cookies for this very same domain and path in the `HTTPCookieStorage` - like, do they get merged, or does your custom header get discarded...